# Вывод пунктов меню и текста для них из JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax

Имеется некоторый ветвистый JSON файл. 
Из него осуществляется вывод пунктов меню. С этим я справился.
Но каким способом осуществить вывод данных в зависимости от выбранного пункта меню ?

структура из разряда:

```
{
    "links" : [
        {
            "linkname" : "link1",
            "linkId" : 0,
            "text" : [
                {
                    "titlename": "1 title of link1",
                    "text": "текст который надо вывести при клике на 1 title of link1"
                },
                {
                    "titlename": "2 title of link1",
                    "text": "текст который надо вывести при клике на 2 title of link1"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "linkname" : "link2",
            "linkId"  : 1,
            "text" : [
                {
                    "titlename": "1 title of link2",
                    "text": "текст который надо вывести при клике на 1 title of link2"
                },
                {
                    "titlename": "2 title of link2",
                    "text": "текст который надо вывести при клике на 2 title of link2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

```html
<aside class="main-content__aside-menu">
</aside>
```

```html
<ul class="list">
                  <li>dumb text</li>
                  <li>dumb text</li>
                  <li>dumb text</li>
                  <li>dumb text</li>
                  <li>dumb text</li>
                  <li>dumb text</li>
                  <li>dumb text</li>
                  <li>dumb text</li>
                  <li>dumb text</li>
                  <li>dumb text</li>
                  <li>dumb text</li>
                </ul>
```

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

  let menu = document.querySelector('.main-content__aside-menu'),
      list = document.querySelector('.list'),
      textBox = document.querySelector('.text'),
      menuItemList = [],
      titleItemList = [];

  let url = '../data.json';

  let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', url, true);

  request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');

  request.onload = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      let data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      setMenu(menu, data);

      const menuItem = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item');
      menuItemList = Array.from(menuItem);
      setTitles(list, data, menu, menuItemList);

      const listItem = document.querySelectorAll('.list-item');
      titleItemList = Array.from(listItem);
      setText(textBox, data, list, titleItemList);
    }
  }

  request.send();
});

function setMenu(menu, data) {
  data.links.forEach(function (object) {
    let a = document.createElement('a');
    a.setAttribute('href', '#');
    a.classList.add('menu-item');
    a.innerHTML = object.linkName;
    menu.appendChild(a);
  });
}

function setTitles(list, data, menu, index) {
  menu.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    let target = event.target.closest('.menu-item'),
        targetIndex = index.indexOf(target),
        linkIndex = 0;   

    list.innerHTML = '';

    data.links.forEach(function (object) {
      if (object.linkId == targetIndex){
        for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(object.text).length; i++){
          let li = document.createElement('li');
          li.innerHTML = `<a class="list-item" href="#">${object.text[i].textTitle}</a>`;
          list.appendChild(li);
        }
      }
    });

    const listItem = document.querySelectorAll('.list-item');
    titleItemList = Array.from(listItem);
    linkIndex = data.links[targetIndex].linkId;

    console.log(linkIndex);

    setText(list, titleItemList, data, linkIndex);

  });
}

function setText(list, index, data, linkindex) {
  console.log(linkindex);
  list.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    let target = event.target.closest('.list-item'),
        targetIndex = index.indexOf(target),
        textBox = document.querySelector('.text');

        console.log(linkindex);

    // textBox.innerHTML = `<p>${data.links[linkindex].text[targetIndex].textContent}</p>`;

  });
```

UPDATE: Теперь проблема в том, что.. почему то в функции setText присваивается несколько переменных. Ну то есть когда вызывается функция setTitles я присваиваю linkIndex значение и это значение передаю в setText. Если клик происходит несколько раз, то передаётся сразу несколько значений. То есть нажму два раза нулевой пункт - выведет 0 0 и в таком духе.

Comment: Обновил код. 
Ну допустим человек нажал на пункт который я вывел в menu из JSON.
При нажатии ему должны вывестись данные которые вложены в этот пункт меню в JSON файле. То есть при нажатии на "link1" на экране должно вывести текст из вложенного элемента "titlename". При нажатии на этот "titlename" должно вывести текст из "text"

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Answer (score 1):

Вызов

```
menuItem = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item')
```

до отработки функции `appendJSON` вернет пустой список. Т.к. на этот момент никаких элементов в `menu` нет.

Соответственно вызов

```
menuItemList = Array.from(menuItem);
```

вернет пустой массив

Как должно быть:

```js
let menu;
const menuItemList = [];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  menu = document.querySelector('.main-content__aside-menu');
  getJSON();
});

function appendJSON(data) {
  data.links.forEach(function(object) {
    let a = document.createElement('a');
    a.setAttribute('href', '#');
    a.classList.add('menu-item');
    a.innerHTML = object.linkname;
    menu.appendChild(a);
    menuItemList.push(a);
  });
}
```

А еще лучше - без глобальных переменных

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const menu = document.querySelector('.main-content__aside-menu');
  let menuItemList = [];

  let url = '../data.json';

  let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', url, true);

  request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');

  request.onload = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      let data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      appendJSON(menunu, data);
      const menuItem = menu.querySelectorAll('.menu-item');
      menuItemList = Array.from(menuItem);
    }
  }
  request.send();

  menu.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    let target = event.target.closest('.menu-item');
    console.log(menuItemList.indexOf(target));
  });

});

function appendJSON(menu, data) {
  data.links.forEach(function(object) {
    let a = document.createElement('a');
    a.setAttribute('href', '#');
    a.classList.add('menu-item');
    a.innerHTML = object.linkname;
    menu.appendChild(a);
  });
}
```

Comment: да, это хорошо работает, только мой способ конечно обернулся неудачей, так как я не могу связаться с данными которые спарсил в другой функции которая должна вызываться по клику.

Comment: @4rmr3d1 Ничего не понял из вашего комментария

Comment: Ну смысл в том чтобы при событии клик отображались вложенные данные из .json файла. Я это реализовал просто вложив еще одну функцию и так же передал туда спарсенный файл.

Comment: @4rmr3d1 тогда в чем проблема?

Comment: Проблема в том, что я не могу достучаться до уровней ниже в .json файле. Я не могу передать id пункта на который я нажал в другую функцию которая должна показывать текст при нажатии на вложенный пункт. Звучит запутанно конечно, но в приведённом .json файле намечена структура